# Custom Add to cart link - WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

As I have a custom product page, I would like to add a custom add to cart button. I have tried the following:

http://"website"/cart/?add-to-cart="product id"&variation_id="variation id"&attribute_"attribute slug name"

This used to work but since I updated woocommerce it doesn't work anymore. Any ideas on how I could create a custom add to cart link for variable products that redirects me to the cart page upon clicking the add to cart button? Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Make sure you use attriubute_pa to prefix your attribute names like this example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&variation_id=456&attribute_pa_colour=black

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew I will give it a try and get back to you ASAP!